# Использовать прокси с авторизацией, через Selenium на java

Tags: java, firefox, proxy, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Задача: запустить браузер с подключение через прокси для подключения к которому необходимо проходить аутентификацию.

---

Для установки прокси в браузере вручную, прописываю адрес и порт в настройках соединения браузера. После этого, при первом доступе к любому серверу в браузере вылезает диалоговое окно для прохождения авторизации (basic authorization). После ее прохождения все запросы проходят через прокси.

В селениуме пробовал делать так:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("<login>:<password>@<address>:<port>");
proxy.setSslProxy("<login>:<password>@<address>:<port>");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

В этом случае в конфигурации подключения браузера на место адреса прокси устанавливается `<login>`, а порт дэфолтный ( ноль ). Если дописать `http://`, то вместо адреса вставляется `http`, а порт ноль.

---

И еще, пробовал так:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("<address>:<port>");
proxy.setSslProxy("<address>:<port>");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

В этом случае адрес и порт прописываются правильно и после запуска браузера (на строке `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`) появляется диалоговое окно с текстом `Прокси «moz-proxy://<address>:<port>» запрашивает имя пользователя и пароль. Сайт сообщает: «proxy»` и полями для ввода логина и пароля, выполнение программы приостанавливается, что не дает возможность воспользоваться созданным объектом `driver` для переключения на окно и ввести логин и пароль (`driver.switchTo().alert()....`).

---

Также нагуглил вариант:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("<address>:<port>");
proxy.setSslProxy("<address>:<port>");
proxy.setSocksUsername("<login>");
proxy.setSocksPassword("<password>");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Но результат такой-же как и во втором случае.

---

Работать должно как минимум в Firefox, а в идеале еще и в PhantomJS. В принципе, не будет лишней поддержка Chrome, но это не обязательно.

---

### **Update**

Неужели никто не сталкивался с таким?

Я пробовал использовать еще такой вариант:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); // DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("signon.autologin.proxy" , true);
profile.setPreference("network.websocket.enabled", false);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", false);
profile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies", false);
profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
profile.setPreference("network.auth.use-sspi", false);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "<address>");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", <port>);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "<address>");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", <port>);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,  profile);
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setSocksUsername("<login>");
proxy.setSocksPassword("<password>");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://2ip.ru");
```

Если устанавливать конфигурацию прокси через профайл фаерфокса ( profile.setPreference(...) ), то окно для авторизации через прокси появляется немного раньше окна браузера (браузер запускается примерно за 1 секунду, а окно для авторизации появляется примерно на пол секунды раньше) и при этом, в отличии от вариантов реализации из предыдущего сообщения, не блокирует главное окно (которое запускается/отображается немножко позже). Также в этом варианте выполнение программы не приостанавливается на строке создания драйвера (`new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`). Программа приостанавливается на строке `driver.get("http://2ip.ru");` , браузер при этом ожидает ответ от 2ip.ru, до тех пор пока я не введу вручную данные для авторизации прокси, если авторизация не удалась, то вместо запрошенной страницы получаю сообщение - "Прокси-сервер отказывается принимать соединения".

Вопрос: как можно получить доступ к окну авторизации для дальнейшего ввода логина и пародя или как пройти авторизацию на прокси сервере не выводя окно для авторизации ( примерно как я пробовал: proxy.setSocksUsername(""); proxy.setSocksPassword("" ); )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил через AutoItX4Java:

```
private void mozProxyAuth(String login, String password) {
    String JACOB_DLL_TO_USE = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("32") ? "jacob-1.18-x86.dll" : "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), JACOB_DLL_TO_USE);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    if (x.winWait("Требуется аутентификация", null, 10)) {
        x.winActivate("Требуется аутентификация");
        x.send(login + "{TAB}" + password + "{ENTER}", false);
    }
}
```